# Регулярные выражения, проверка строк на соответсвие c#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Возникли вопросы по регулярным выражениям. Данный метод производит проверку строк на соответствие формату.
К примеру:
обычная нотация - 3.5;
научная нотация - 5*10, 5e5;
Не число - любые буквы.

```
static void FindNotation(string number)
        {
            string simpleNumber = @"^-*[0-9,\.]+$";
            string scientificNumber = @"^-*[0-9,\.\d[e|\D\d]+$";

            if (Regex.IsMatch(number, simpleNumber, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                Console.WriteLine("Это число в обычной нотации");
            else if (Regex.IsMatch(number, scientificNumber, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                Console.WriteLine("Это число в научной нотации");
            else 
                Console.WriteLine("Это не число!");
        }
```

При вводе чисел из обычной и научной нотации, метод срабатывает корректно. При вводе букв, он всегда совпадает с регулярным выражением `@"^-*[0-9,\.\d[e|\D\d]+$";` Можете подсказать в чем ошибка моего выражения? Либо где можно почитать более подробно об этом.

Comment: Чтобы проверить на "не число", достаточно поставить `\D`

Comment: А ваша регулярка вообще странная, почему-то 3 раза повторяется одно и то же `\d`, а также есть ему противоположное `\D`

Comment: @dIm0n Действительно, поправил. '''@"^-*[0-9,\.\d[[e]|\D]]+$";'''. Теперь проверка на "не число" проходит для всех символов кроме "e".

Comment: Советую воспользоваться каким-нибудь онлайн-редактором. Например, https://regex101.com/r/wzk4NS/1. Там объясняется, что делает регулярка по частям. Сейчас у вас зачем-то два подряд символа `]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Описание значения регулярных выражений доступно на английском языке на [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tE8Wnv/1). Ваше регулярное выражение состоит из следующих частей:

- `^` - начало строки
- `-*` - 0 и более дефисов
- `[0-9,\.\d[e|\D\d]+` - один и более любых символов, так как

  - `0-9` - находит любую цифру
  - `,` - запятую
  - `\.` - точку
  - `\d` - опять цифру
  - `[` - символ `[`
  - `e` - букву `e`
  - `|` - знак `|`
  - `\D` - любую не-цифру
  - `\d` - опять цифру
- `$` - конец строки.

Как видите, `[0-9,\.\d[e|\D\d]+` = `[\D\d]+` = `(?s).+`, то есть это тот самый шаблон, который находит любой непустой текст.

Возможно, вам следует использовать

```
^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?$
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/B71hDn/1). `5*10` оно не найдет, правда, это не похоже на число.

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[+-]?` - необязательный символ `+` или `-`
- `\d*\.?\d+` - 0 и более цифр, необязательная точка, 1 и более цифр
- `(?:` - начало необязательной незахватывающей подмаски:

  - `[eE]` - `e` или `E`
  - `[+-]?` - необязательный символ `+` или `-`
  - `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `)?` - один или ноль повторов
- `$` - конец строки.